# From df device name to physical drive name (vendor / type)

Tags: linux, hard-disk, disk-usage, block-device

Seeing the device name by df, is it somehow possible to resolve it to the physical drive name such as **vendor / type**.

```
/dev/sda3               915.4G     34.9G    880.0G   4% /share/HDA_DATA
/dev/sdd3                 1.8T    668.1G      1.1T  36% /share/HDD_DATA
```

I have learnt that I find some info in [sys/block](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25514/linux-2-6-32-busybox-identify-physical-sd-device), but I do not find the vendor's type name in there?

-- Added --

My system is a Linux based QNAP NAS, so things might be a little different there.

-- Added as of Steven's answer --

```
[~] # hdparm -I /dev/sdb3

/dev/sdb3:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Maybe you have more luck with `dmesg` or `dmesg | grep -C10 sda`.

Comment: Or `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda` (requires root privileges).

Comment: The dmesg approach works, thx. Will rate your answer below as correct, and add a comment.

Comment: Similar messages will appear in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/dmesg. Exact file name is highly dependent on distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo lshw -class disk
  *-cdrom                 
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: CDDVDW SH-S223Q
       vendor: TSSTcorp
       physical id: 0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: SB02
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: WDC WD1600AAJS-0
       vendor: Western Digital
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 01.0
       serial: WD-WMAV2P964464
       size: 149GiB (160GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=000c0805
  *-disk
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: signature=a39eabc7
```

Comment: On my QNAP NAS I do not find this lshw command. Checked /sbin /usr/sbin  Any idea where else I could find it? I believe you this is working, unfortunately not on my Linux based NAS.

Comment: I am using the dmesg approach, as in jippie's comment above. Will rate this as answer anyway, since it is correct.

Answer (score 4):

The QNAP NAS products run firmware that is essentially a custom Linux distro. It is quite spartan, with a minimal set of command line tools (and many of those provided by `busybox`). Fortunately, there is a decent implementation of `hdparm` in there, so you should be able to query a drive, as follows:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

Here's the output I get from a "QNAP TS-239 Pro NAS" with a "Western Digital RE4 1TB" drive (output is verbatim, except for the drive's serial number, which I have purposely obscured):

```
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       WDC WD1003FBYX-01Y7B0                   
    Serial Number:      AB-CDEF01234567
    Firmware Revision:  01.01V01
Standards:
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors: 1953525168
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      953869 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:     1000204 MBytes (1000 GB)
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, with device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 0
    Advanced power management level: unknown setting (0x0080)
    Recommended acoustic management value: 128, current value: 254
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    NOP cmd
       *    READ BUFFER cmd
       *    WRITE BUFFER cmd
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Write cache
       *    Power Management feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    SMART feature set
       *    FLUSH CACHE EXT command
       *    Mandatory FLUSH CACHE command 
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set 
       *    48-bit Address feature set 
       *    Automatic Acoustic Management feature set 
            SET MAX security extension
       *    SET FEATURES subcommand required to spinup after power up
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
       *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE cmd
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    SMART self-test 
       *    SMART error logging 
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    168min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 168min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Checksum: correct
```

"Vendor" and "Type" are not explicitly reported by `hdparm`. However, "Model Number" *is* reported, and a quick web search on it should yield anything you need to know about a drive.

Comment: Sounds good, in my case I do get the following response: HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid argument Have updated question.

Comment: @Horst: Try `hdparm -I /dev/sdb` instead. `/dev/sdb3` is most likely not a drive, but a partition, and `hdparm` needs a drive.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but no luck. I have tried sda, sdb, sdb3, sda3 etc, all the same issue `HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid argument` Run it as admin, which should be root on QNAP, sudo I cannot find (tried sudo hdparm ...)

Answer (score 3):

Most modern Linux systems use [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) to manage devices. This isn't the case on all embedded devices though; I don't know whether this specific device uses udev.

```
udevadm info -n /dev/sda3 -a
udevadm info -n /dev/sda3 -q property
```

will print everything the system knows about `/dev/sda3`. This is the same info you'll find in `/sys`, but udev does the work of walking down the hierarchy to collect all the data.

Comment: Again no luck with my QNAP system, `udevadm` not available. Nevertheless we do have a comprehensive summary of commands here right now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Install `gsmartcontrol` a GUI tool with loads of information: http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de/home/images/info_identity.png

```
gsmartcontrol (1)    - Hard disk drive health inspection tool
```

Comment: Useful hint, but the system is a QNAP NAS, I cannot install GUI related tools. Thanks anyway, and sorry that I did not tell this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I discovered command:

`/sbin/get_hd_smartinfo`

When run with out args prints usage guide.

To connect disk number to device use like this:

`/sbin/get_hd_smartinfo -d 2 -i 1`

Press ctrl-c to terminate and it will print "Save file to /tmp/sdX_smart_zzzzzzz" where sdX is your device.

```
[/var/log] # /sbin/get_hd_smartinfo -d 2 -i 1 
001 Raw_Read_Error_Rate          215244560 119 099 006 OK
...
242 Lifetime_Reads_To_Host       23449824883497 100 253 000 OK
^CCatch interrupt Singal,Interrupt ..
Save file to /tmp/sdb_smart_563ffc1c
```