# Detect when sdcard removed

Tags: linux, debian, shell-script, sd-card

I'm working with a small Arm board (Emtrion) running Debian Linux. Emtrion has provided an sdcard image that can update the boards flash. I would like to extend the simple update script, so that when it is finished, it waits for the user to eject the sdcard, and when that happens `reboot`. So I'm looking for some simple script mechanism to basically wait for that event. I tried something like:

```
tail -f -n 1 /var/log/messages | grep -m 1 "card removed"
reboot
```

My thinking was that I would just troll `messages`, and that the `-m 1` flag would cause `grep` to exit when it found its first match. Alas, that doesn't seem to work, it just keeps going. So I'm hoping there's some other trick/technique I can use. I'm really after something I can do inside of the existing script. I don't have `expect` in this image, so that's not an option. It appears to be running `busybox`.

Comment: Does your embedded system include `udev`? If yes then you can probably hook in to that to be notified when a device is removed, without any log file trolling hacks.

Comment: I think it is not using `udev`. None of the conf files for it seem to exist. I do have an `\sbin\mdev` which is a symlink to `busybox`

Comment: busybox doesn't have `udev`, it has `mdev` instead. i think this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25514/linux-2-6-32-busybox-identify-physical-sd-device) might have what you want.